# double problem in xcode or me doing something wrong

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, variables, double

I would guess it's the simplest thing but it's really confusing me.  I'm sure I've successfully used doubles before but now I'm having trouble.

I just made a new 'test' project to see if I can get it working, but all I'm trying to do is set a double value.

So in the View Controller's viewDidLoad i've typed:

```
double z = 2938.09;
NSLog(@"z = %d", z);
```

I would expect it to output 'z = 2938.09' but instead I get 'z = 343597384'

double z = 3.4 returns z = 858993459

Also most integer values report back as z = 0, however not always (sometimes another strange number as above is spewed out)

Am I missing something here or it something strange going on??

Even tried stuff like

```
NSString *newString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"3.4"];
double z = [newString.text doubleValue];
NSLog(@"z = %d", z);
[newString release];
```

but still get the crazy z = 858993459 :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double is a double precision float, and so, to print you should use the same way used to print floats:

```
NSString *newString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"3.4"];
double z = [newString.text doubleValue];
NSLog(@"z = %f", z);
[newString release];
```

`%d` is used to print signed int.

Have a look at this link with the format specifiers for NSLog: http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSLog

Comment: Ahh - what a beautiful sight it is to see z = 3.400000! Thanks guys, now I can get stuck into my proper code and hopefully sort things out.Tv

Answer (score 5):

For printing the Double value use %f instead of %d.

NSlog format specifiers

%@     Object

%d, %i signed int

%u     unsigned

%f     float/double

%x, %X hexadecimal int

%o     octal

%zu    size_t

%p     pointer

%e     float/double (in scientific notation)

%g     float/double (as %f or %e, depending on value)

%s     C string (bytes)

%S     C string (unichar)

%.*s   Pascal string (requires two arguments, pass pstr[0] as the first, pstr+1 as the second)

%c     character

%C     unichar

%lld   long long

%llu   unsigned long long

%Lf    long double

Comment: Ahh - what a beautiful sight it is to see z = 3.400000! Thanks guys, now I can get stuck into my proper code and hopefully sort things out.Tv