# Why does my objective-c code output an incorrect area?

Tags: objective-c

I ran the code below, it ouput area to be 1 instead of 12.568 Can someone please check what is wrong with the code

```
   #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

   int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
   {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    
    //  constant
    #define PI 3.142fat
   float area;
   int r=2;
   area = PI * (r*r);
   NSLog(@"Area is %d", area);
    
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
  }
```

2023-05-26 12:36:48.839 main[16:16] Area is 1

Comment: `NSLog(@"Area is %d", area);` -> `NSLog(@"Area is %f", area);`

Comment: FYI - Don't define your own constant for `PI`. Foundation already provides `M_PI` which is a lot more accurate.

Comment: And as a follow-on to the comment by @Larme, see the [String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFStrings/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265) documentation. You'll need to know those for things like `NSLog` and `NSString stringWithFormat:`.

Comment: @Larme could you please turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [double problem in xcode or me doing something wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717038/double-problem-in-xcode-or-me-doing-something-wrong)